# selecting last n dated records for each in a group

Tags: mysql

I hope someone can help. I have a table....

```
name    date    number
John    2014-01-01    5
Sally   2014-01-01    7
John    2013-12-24    2
Sally   2013-12-24    7
John    2013-11-10    1
Sally   2012-11-10    8
```

I want to get the latest 2 (or x) records for each person eg

```
John    2014-01-01    5
John    2013-12-24    2
Sally   2014-01-01    7
Sally   2013-12-24    7
```

I don't know where to start. If anyone can shed some light on this I would be really grateful. It would also be good (if you have time) if you could explain the solution for learning purposes!

Many thanks

Jules

Comment: I think this question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.name = x.name 
   AND y.date >= x.date 
 GROUP 
    BY x.name
     , x.date 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2 
 ORDER 
    BY name,date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(Distinct Names) "yourtable" 

Group By Names
```

the result of count you will multiply by x and tis will be the limit of your next query meaning:

```
Select Distinct Names,date,number from "yourtablename"

limit Count(Distinct Names)*X

order by Names
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for some reason. It might have been something I was doing, but with my limited (although growing) knowledge I couldn't figure it out. Strawberry's solution worked 'straight out of the box' though so I have selected his answer. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: No problem..take care..Strws answer is more neat anyway